# Set height of 3 elements, taking largest value, across multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a layout of divs all floating left, with a column count of 3. Inside these layers is text with varying length, as such the layers are at different heights and so not aligning correctly and also not looking very good as the borders do not match up in height.

I could set a fixed height for all the divs but this will leave huge white space on some rows so I have wrote some JQuery to take the largest value of all the divs and set all the heights to that height so they line up correctly. The script is:

```
var sectionheight = new Array(); //set empty array
$(".section-title").each(function () { //get all div elements
    var value = $(this).height(); //get div height
    sectionheight.push(value); //write height to array
});
var newsectionheight = Math.max.apply(Math, sectionheight); //get largest value in array
$('.section-title').height(newsectionheight); //set height of all elements to largest
```

This works fine but in the design some rows only have 1 line of text and so it is adjusting that row to be as big as say the top row with 5 lines of text.

What I am trying to achieve is have it take the first 3 divs, get the largest value then set those 3 div heights to that value. Then repeat this for the 4th to 6th div and so on (as the divs are in columns of 3)

I can do a really long winded solution with `$(".section-title").eq(2)` but I can imagine this is not an ideal way of doing it.

Any advice is appreciated

Edit example of some divs (css is not visible in the html, just for the example):

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="section-title" style="width: 30%; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">some text and a longer title than the other rows</div>
    <div class="section-title" style="width: 30%; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">some text</div>
    <div class="section-title" style="width: 30%; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">some text not as long</div>
    <div class="section-title" style="width: 30%; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">some text</div>
    <div class="section-title" style="width: 30%; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">short text</div>
    <div class="section-title" style="width: 30%; margin-right: 5px; float: left;">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your markup as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $sections = $('.section-title');

$sections.filter(':nth-child(3n-2)').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $els = $this.nextAll(':lt(2)').addBack();

    var sectionheight = new Array();
    $els.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).height();
        sectionheight.push(value);
    });
    var newsectionheight = Math.max.apply(Math, sectionheight);
    $els.height(newsectionheight);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6JqB2/)

Answer (score 0):

ok try this:

```
function setHeight(){
        var max =  -1;
            // this will give you maximum height of your div
        $(document).find('.test-div').each(function() {
            var h = $(this).height();
            max = h > max ? h : max;
        });
            // varible-div is the division whose height keeps changeing
        $(document).find('.variable-div').each(function(){
            var presentHeight=$(this).parents('.test-div').height(),
            difference=max-presentHeight;
            if(difference > 0){
                $(this).height($(this).height()+difference);
            }
        });
}
```